# XAMPP PHP ZipArchive::open() size limit?

Tags: php, xampp, 32bit-64bit, php-ziparchive

I am trying to open a ZIP file using PHP 5.6.24 on Windows Server 2008. As it is running XAMPP, Apache and PHP are 32bit.
The file in question is 2.5 GB and cannot be opened, ZipArchive::open() returns the error code 19 (Not a zip archive). However, the file checks out okay. Using the same method on Linux (64bit) with the same PHP version, there is no error on the same file.
I have removed entries from the Zip file to reduce the file size to 1.9 GB, and PHP has no issues processing that file.
The code is simple:

```
$za = new ZipArchive();
$err = $za->open('file.zip');
```

The only thing I can imagine is that for some reason, 32bit PHP cannot cope with archives > 2GB, but I have not found anything on this. I found mentioning of a 4 GB limit and of 64k files, but that doesn't apply in this case.
Is there anything I can do, maybe a configuration option, to be able to process this file?

Comment: `32bit PHP cannot cope with archives > 2GB` Exactly! 32-bit signed integer limit is 2,147,483,647 (2GB) and the file pointer in 32-bit PHP is a 32-bit signed integer. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't have a php.ini `eliminate.32bit.restrictions` setting to turn off that restriction

Comment: You can only fix this by installing a 64bit version of PHP (probably need a 64bit version of Apache too).

Comment: I can access the whole file in PHP, so there are parts that can actually cope with >2GB. I cannot see a reason for a file pointer to be signed, an unsigned file pointer would account for the 4 GB limit.
Anyway, seems the ZipArchive cannot do that.